# What are the positive effects of adding celery to a sauce?

Tags: sauce, celery

Many sauces include celery. It's not a flavour I'm particularly keen on, particularly in sauces so I'm wondering why it's included. Is it included simply as a flavour or does it serve some other purpose?

Comment: My wife absolutely hates carrots and celery by themselves, but actually loves food I cook with mirepoix. If you haven't tried using it in a mirepoix I'd suggest giving it a shot just to see how the combination works because it does act a little differently combined with other things than by itself.

Comment: I couldn't agree more I'm not a fan of celery as a flavour on it's own but balanced properly in a dish it just works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Celery is an aromatic, and 1/3 of a [mirepoix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirepoix_%28cuisine%29). It's used for the base flavor of a lot of French and Cajun/Creole cuisine. It doesn't serve any important chemical role that I'm aware of, so you can omit or substitute it if you really don't like the flavor.

Comment: Right, one of the 4 aromatic herbs, as I was taught. Leek, Celery, Parsley and Carrots.

Comment: None of those are herbs.

Comment: Excuse my English: Vegetables.

Answer (score 7):

When used in sauces as a building block (e.g. *mirepoix*, *soffrito*, the Louisianian Trinity), celery is used to provide only flavour. These flavours come from terpenes which provide aromas of citrus, pine, and (to me) grass, as well as a pleasing bitterness. Other flavours are provided by phthalides, which celery shares with walnuts.

[Research indicates](http://www.science20.com/news_releases/study_phthalides_are_the_magic_in_celery_that_makes_soups_taste_better) that the same phthalides, while largely flavourless, enhance umami flavours in food. In addition, they seem to have some [health benefits](http://www.phthalides.com/).